# How to make millis() to count 1 sec exactly in arduino?

Tags: arduino

I am working on a project on Arduino in which Arduino have to count 1 sec and on every sec Arduino has to run a certain function (every sec I mean a complete sec not an instance of a sec).

```
if (((millis()) % 1000) == 0)
{
    tym_countdown();
    Serial.println("Refresh");
```

What is happening as you can see below my Arduino is counting instances rather only complete secs.

```
 20:54:04.145 -> Refresh
 20:54:04.145 -> Refresh
 20:54:05.119 -> Refresh
 20:54:05.119 -> Refresh
 20:54:05.119 -> Refresh
 20:54:05.119 -> Refresh
 20:54:05.119 -> Refresh
 20:54:05.165 -> Refresh
 20:54:05.165 -> Refresh
 20:54:05.165 -> Refresh
 20:54:06.103 -> Refresh
 20:54:06.103 -> Refresh
 20:54:06.103 -> Refresh
 20:54:06.150 -> Refresh
```

Code:

```
#define X 13
#define Y 12
#define Z 11

char txt[15];
char tym[6];
int index,tym_index;
int pin_status_array[2][3]={0,0,0,0,0,0};

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(X,OUTPUT);// setting the pin flow of control as output
  pinMode(Y,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Z,OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial)
  {
    ;  //to wait for pc to connect
  }
  Serial.println("\nHome Automation");
  initial_dash_print();  


}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  read_incomming_serial_data();
  if(((millis())%1000)==0)
  {
    tym_countdown();
    Serial.println("Refresh");
  }
  turn_on_n_off();

}


void initial_dash_print() //to print dashes
{ Serial.println("-----------------------------------------------");
  Serial.println("give me some command"); //ask for command
   }

void read_incomming_serial_data()// read incoming data from serial
{
 if(Serial.available()>0) 
  { delay(17); // delay for arduino to wait and read commands,1ms per char.
    index=0;
    tym_index=0;
    while(Serial.available()>0)   //if serial available
    { char inchar=Serial.read();
      txt[index]=inchar; // add char to txt string
      index++;// increment to where to write next

      if(index>4)
      { tym[tym_index]=inchar;
        tym_index++; 
      }
     }
   Serial.print(txt);

   check_data_from_serial();

   }
  }

void check_data_from_serial() // to check data from serial
{ 
  if(strncmp(txt,"ON X",4)==0)
  { 
    pin_status_array[0][0]=1;
    if(tym_index!=0)
    {     
     tym_update(X);
      }
    }
  else if(strncmp(txt,"OFF X",5)==0)
  { 
    pin_status_array[0][0]=0;
    }
    if(strncmp(txt,"ON Y",4)==0)
  { 
    pin_status_array[0][1]=1;
    if(tym_index!=0)
    {     
     tym_update(Y);
      }
    }
  else if(strncmp(txt,"OFF Y",5)==0)
  { 
    pin_status_array[0][1]=0;
    }
    if(strncmp(txt,"ON Z",4)==0)
  { 
    pin_status_array[0][2]=1;
    if(tym_index!=0)
    {     
     tym_update(Z);
      }
    }
  else if(strncmp(txt,"OFF Z",5)==0)
  { 
    pin_status_array[0][2]=0;
    }
  else if(txt=="STATUS")
  { 
      }


}

void tym_update(int pin) // update time row
{ 
  int temp=pin-13; // pin to array column equivalent
  pin_status_array[1][temp]=atoi(tym);
}

void tym_countdown() //to perform time countdown
{ for(int temp_index=0; temp_index<4; temp_index++)
  {
   if(pin_status_array[0][temp_index]==1 && pin_status_array[1][temp_index]>0) // '0' => txt '1' => tym
   {
     int temp=pin_status_array[1][temp_index];
     temp--;
     pin_status_array[1][temp_index]=temp;
     if(temp==0)
     {
       pin_status_array[0][temp_index]=0; //turn off
     }
   }
  }
}

void turn_on_n_off()
{
  if(pin_status_array[0][0]==1)
  {
    digitalWrite(X,HIGH);
  }
  if(pin_status_array[0][0]==0)
  {
    digitalWrite(X,LOW);
  }
  if(pin_status_array[0][1]==1)
  {
    digitalWrite(Y,HIGH);
  }
  if(pin_status_array[0][1]==0)
  {
    digitalWrite(Y,LOW);
  }
  if(pin_status_array[0][2]==1)
  {
    digitalWrite(Z,HIGH);
  }
  if(pin_status_array[0][2]==0)
  {
    digitalWrite(Z,LOW);
  }

}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to trigger an action exactly every 1 second then you should try using an Interrupt Service Routine (ISR). Depending on what board you are using then this can be done using the [Timer library](https://playground.arduino.cc/code/timer1). You'll need to keep the ISR short or you could defer the processing to the `loop()` function.

If you don't have such hard realtime requirements and only need to perform an action once per second then you can record the last time the action ran in `loop()`. Then check if at least 1000 ms have elapsed since the last iteration of `loop()`.

e.g.

```
unsigned long lastTriggerTime = 0;

void loop() {
  read_incomming_serial_data();
  auto currentLoopTime = millis();
  if(currentLoopTime - lastTriggerTime >= 1000)
  {
    lastTriggerTime = currentLoopTime;
    tym_countdown();
```

Comment: problem i am facing is Arduino counting some bits of instances. just as similar in case of bouncing keys problem.

Comment: i want it to funtion exactly at a complete 1 sec not at .9,.8,.7.

Comment: "it's not working" - in what way? Is it running more than once per second? If you need something to run as close to every 1000ms then you need to use an ISR.

Comment: print the value of `currentLoopTime - lastTriggerTime` inside your if statement to confirm this.

Comment: ya, I got it. sry for the late response and thanks for the help :-).

Answer (score 0):

You can "synchronize"  blt's suggestion to exact 1000 ms intervals easily:

```
unsigned long lastTriggerTime = 0;

void loop() {
  read_incomming_serial_data();
  unsigned long currentLoopTime = millis();
  if(currentLoopTime - lastTriggerTime >= 1000)
  {
     lastTriggerTime += 1000;  // will increment in 1000's steps
     tym_countdown();
...
```

Of course, this has nothing to do with real world seconds and has a limited accuracy of about 0.1%

Comment: ya, I got it. sry for the late response and thanks for the help :-).